# Powershell Multi-Dimensional Array Iteration

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, acl

Fairly new to Powershell. I am trying to apply a few different concepts to this solution.
I want to create a Folder and then use a function that is meant to help set ACLs to a folder. A Multi-dimensional array intended to hold templates of folder names to be used in a variety of purposes and departments. The Numbers are just place-holders.
I run with the what-if addition and I get no errors but it feels like I made a mistake somewhere still.
I researched a lot of looping and iterating through Multi-dimensional arrays in Powershell and didn't find a great match to my intention.

```
function Set-permissions {
    Param($assign_to_Read, $assign_to_RW, $path)
    #Create new ACL Object
    $acl_main = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
    #Create Read Object
    $ACL_Read = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($assign_to_Read, "Read", "Allow")
    #Set first access object to ACL: Read
    $acl_main.SetAccessRule($ACL_Read)
    #Create Modify Object
    $ACL_RW = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($assign_to_RW, "Modify", "Allow")
    #Add access object to ACL: Modify 
    $acl_main.AddAccessRule($ACL_RW)
    #Pipe the 
    $acl_main | Set-Acl -Path $path -WhatIf
    }

New-Item -Path $top_level -Name $result -ItemType "directory"
#Create Subdirectories and Assign Read and RW ACL
$newEmployeePath = $top_level + '\' + $result

$employee_template = @(
("1 ",
"ACL_Read_1 ",
"ACL_RW_1 "),

("2 ",
"ACL_Read_2 ",
"ACL_RW_2 "),

("3 ",
"ACL_Read_3 ",
"ACL_RW_3 "),
)
ForEach($folder in $employee_template ){
    #Create the Folder from first location in the array
    New-Item -Path $newEmployeePath -Name $folder[0]
    #Set permissions for Read and RW on the folder.
    Set-permissions $folder[1] $folder[2] $newEmployeePath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off using an array of **objects** instead:

```
$employee_template = [PsCustomObject]@{Folder = 'EmployeeFolder1'; ReadAccess = 'EmployeeOrGroupRead1'; WriteAccess = 'EmployeeOrGroupWrite1'},
                     [PsCustomObject]@{Folder = 'EmployeeFolder2'; ReadAccess = 'EmployeeOrGroupRead2'; WriteAccess = 'EmployeeOrGroupWrite2'},
                     [PsCustomObject]@{Folder = 'EmployeeFolder3'; ReadAccess = 'EmployeeOrGroupRead3'; WriteAccess = 'EmployeeOrGroupWrite3'} 
                     # and so on
```

Then use that object array something like:

```
foreach ($employee in $employee_template) {
    # Create the Folder (suppress console output)
    $newEmployeePath = Join-Path -Path $top_level -ChildPath $employee.Folder
    $null = New-Item -Path $newEmployeePath -ItemType Directory -Force
    # Set permissions for Read and RW on the folder.
    Set-Permissions $newEmployeePath $employee.ReadAccess $employee.WriteAccess
}
```

P.S. for the above, either change the order of parameters in your function to the more logical

```
Param($path, $assign_to_Read, $assign_to_RW)
```

or call the function using

```
Set-Permissions $employee.ReadAccess $employee.WriteAccess $newEmployeePath
```

---

Of course, you could easily create a CSV file and use `Import-Csv` to get your object array of employee folders and access so you don't have to create that in the code:

Example CSV:

```
"Folder","ReadAccess","WriteAccess"
"EmployeeFolder1","EmployeeOrGroupRead1","EmployeeOrGroupWrite1"
"EmployeeFolder2","EmployeeOrGroupRead2","EmployeeOrGroupWrite2"
"EmployeeFolder3","EmployeeOrGroupRead3","EmployeeOrGroupWrite3"
```

Comment: Thanks! I do prefer a more Object-Oriented approach. Was missing the path to the nested folders so it did not work as intended. Also I split it into two loops, create the folders first then assign the permissions. 

ForEach($employee in $employee_template ){
    #Create the Folder from first location in the array
    New-Item -Path $newEmployeePath -Name $employee.Folder -ItemType 'directory'
    }
ForEach($employee in $employee_template ){
    $sub_folder_path = $newEmployeePath+"\"+$employee.Folder
    Set-permissions $sub_folder_path $employee.ReadAccess $employee.WriteAccess
    }